# OpenCV orb matching, too many matches

Tags: android, opencv

I've been using Orb detector and descriptor along with BF_hamming matcher. But the thing is when I try to filter the matche using this chunk of code:

```
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
svimatches = matches.toList();

for (int j = 0; j < descriptors1.rows(); j++) {
    distance = svimatches.get(j).distance;
    if (distance < min_distance) {
        min_distance = distance;
    }


    for (int z = 0; z < descriptors1.rows(); z++) {
        if (svimatches.get(z).distance <= 2*min_distance) {
            goodmatcheslist.add(svimatches.get(z));
        }
    }
```

I get too many matches, but when I use 0.25*min_distance then it filters just right.
What is the cause of this? Could anyone reccomend any other types of match filter methods for ORB?

Thanks in Advance,
  K.Š.

Comment: The smaller the match's distance is, the better. By using `0.25*min_distance` you decreased the _acceptance threshold_ and thus got fewer good matches.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to reduce the number of your detected features by increasing your detector's threshold? That's another way of ending up with fewer matches.